# Smoothing for damped wave signal (fixed variance noise, but changing SNR)

Tags: denoising, damping

My colleagues and I are arguing about how to smooth a damped wave signal.

This signal is corrupted by white noise of a steady magnitude.

However the signal damps out as it goes along. So, the SNR and the noise as a standard dev of the signal range, both decrease.

My colleagues say I can denoise it the same the entire time, because the magnitude of the noise is the same. I say I have to adapt, because the SNR is the guiding factor.

Who's right?

Comment: What is the method of denoising ? are you planning to use SNR based filtering(ex. Weiner).

Comment: Complex dual tree wavelets with group sparse thresholding

Comment: When your noise has steady magnitude while your signal damps, how come you are saying your SNR increases?

Comment: Edited to change to decrease. Thank you for catching the error.

Comment: Are you using a model of the signal?